# jquery colorbox загрузить сразу несколько картинок

Tags: jquery

Не могу разобраться как передать в $.colorbox несколько картинок, вот к примеру в fancybox это можно сделать так:

```
$.fancybox.open([
    {
        href : 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg',
        title : 'manual 1st title'
    },
    {
        href : 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg',
        title : '2nd title'
    },
    {
        href : 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_b.jpg',
        title : '3rd title'
    }
])
```

[Этот пример на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2k8EP/)

передаётся массив с картинками и у нас сразу откроется 3 картинки

Как тоже самое сделать в colorbox ?

[Ссылка на colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)

Answer (score 0):

В общем в colorbox так сделать нельзя https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/issues/800